# Using AJAX to run a serverside (VB) function does... nothing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, server-side

Please forgive me for any incorrect technical words used, I'm new to AJAX/Jquery.

I have a function with AJAX in it. It is supossed to execute a serverside function, but it doesn't do anything. I have checked my code multiple times. I use similar code in a different location, and that one works fine.

(I have the necessary scripts imported in the html page)
Here is the function with AJAX:

```
    function pass_on() {
        hide_div("#outer_layout", 500);
        get_din();
        claim_no = document.getElementById("claim_no_label").value;
        tempdin = document.getElementById("temp_din_label").value;
        var data = {};
        data.ReqType = real_index;
        //and so on with rest of the variables.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "claim_form.aspx/submit",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function() {
                window.location = "Defualt.aspx";
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert("FAIL!");
            }
        });
    }
```

and here are the corresponding functions in asp.net page:

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function submit(ByVal ReqType As String, ByVal Claim_Num As String, ByVal Comments As String, ByVal PaymentDate As String, ByVal Payee As String, ByVal IRSNum As String, ByVal AddrStreet1 As String, ByVal AddrStreet2 As String, ByVal AddrCity As String, ByVal AddrState As String, ByVal AddrZip As String, ByVal PaymentAmount As String, ByVal FinalPaymentType As String, ByVal NAVGPercentSettlement As String, ByVal ReasonMemo As String, ByVal ProductCode As String, ByVal DeductAmount As String, ByVal DeductType As String, ByVal ClosedStatus As String, ByVal ReassignTo As String, ByVal TempDin As String) As String
    'Puts values in the DB.
```

Sorry if the text formatting is not very good, this thing refused to work for me :P

Can anyone point out my (probably obvious) mistake ?
If any more details are needed, I'll provide them upon request :)

EDIT: Changed the code to reflect the changes.... Still not working.

Comment: put a breakpoint on the `submit` method, does it get hit?

Comment: add `function pass_on() { alert($); ...` to see if this function is being invoked and if your jQuery is defined at this point.

Comment: @Joey, I get a popup with something like: "funtion(a,b)<more stuff>"

Comment: Ok, I believe it is your URL, try putting the full path to claim_form.aspx, http://localhost/whatever,  instead of the relative path. And it seems Default.aspx is misspelled.

Comment: Tried that, still nothing happens.....
It didn't matter if the default.aspx was correct or not, that section of code doesn't run -_- either.

Comment: @asawyer breakpoint was not hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line

```
 data: '{ReqType: "' + real_index + '", Claim_Num: "' + claim_no + '", Comments: "' + comment_box_form + '", PaymentDate: "' + f4_pay_date + '", Payee: "' + f4_payee + '", IRSNum: "' + f4_irs + '", AddrStreet1: "' + f4_a_1 + '", AddrSteet2: "' + f4_a_2 + '", AddrCity: "' + f4_a_c + '", AddrState: "' + f4_a_s + '", AddrZip: "' + f4_a_z + '", PaymentAmount: "' + f4_pay_amount + '", FinalPaymentType: "' + f4_final + '", NAVGPercentSettlement: "' + f4_navg_set + '", ReasonMemo: "' + f4_reason + '", ProductCode: "' + f4_product + '", DeductAmount: "' + f3_amount + '",DeductType: "' + f3_loss + '", ClosedStatus: "' + f3_close + '", ReassignTo: "' + reassign_to + '", TempDin: "' + tempdin + '" }',
```

is not correct, right off the bat i can see that you are missing a " before ReqType and the : should not be inside of the quotes and the ' should not be there at all

```
 data: {"ReqType": real_index, "Claim_Num" :claim_no,  etc
```

Comment: I have changed that to resemble a different suggestion, now it looks like:

    var data = {};
    data.<variable_name> = <value>;

and then in ajax:

    data: data;

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing:

```
'{ReqType: "' + real_index + '", Claim_Num: "' + claim_no + '", Comments: "' + comment_box_form + '", PaymentDate: "' + f4_pay_date + '", Payee: "' + f4_payee + '", IRSNum: "' + f4_irs + '", AddrStreet1: "' + f4_a_1 + '", AddrSteet2: "' + f4_a_2 + '", AddrCity: "' + f4_a_c + '", AddrState: "' + f4_a_s + '", AddrZip: "' + f4_a_z + '", PaymentAmount: "' + f4_pay_amount + '", FinalPaymentType: "' + f4_final + '", NAVGPercentSettlement: "' + f4_navg_set + '", ReasonMemo: "' + f4_reason + '", ProductCode: "' + f4_product + '", DeductAmount: "' + f3_amount + '",DeductType: "' + f3_loss + '", ClosedStatus: "' + f3_close + '", ReassignTo: "' + reassign_to + '", TempDin: "' + tempdin + '" }'
```

to:

```
var data = {};
data.ReqType = real_index;
data.Claim_Num = claim_no;
data.Comments = comment_box_form;
... etc
```

Then in your ajax:

```
data: data,
```

Comment: I have changed that code to your suggestion, but still the function does not get executed... Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you inspect the console of your browser and see if there are any errors?

Comment: I cannot... IE7, as it also NEEDS to run VBScript. And I cannot install any software.